# Unable to Access Linked Server using Ip Address

Tags: sql-server

Okay, this is my first time attempting to work with a Linked Server in SSMS.  The name of the server is its Ip Address and port like this 44.3.1.112,4230 (not my doing).  I was able to create the linked server using "Create New Linked Server" in SSMS.  However, trying to refer to it in a query using the ip address to copy data from one table into one of its tables is not working.  Now that I have the servers linked, how do I access/call the linked server?

When I try this

```
Select * from [44.3.1.112,4230].CTixAnalysis.dbo.EventType
```

I actually get all of the records from the current database table not the linked server. So I am really not understanding this.  That table on the linked server is empty.  I am actually trying to copy records from the other database.

Tried this:

```
Select * INTO [44.3.1.112,4230].CTixAnalysis.dbo.EventType
from [44.3.12.115,4230].CTixAnalysis.dbo.EventType
```

It gives the error:
**The object name '44.3.1.112,4230.CTixAnalysis.dbo.EventType' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2**.

Comment: Can you share the query you're using? Linked server queries are something like this: select * 
 from [44.3.1.112].yourDatabaseInstance.yourDatabaseSchemaTypicallydbo.TableOrView

Comment: @rlm96 - I don't get that far I get an error as soon as I type "insert into 44.3.1.112,4230".  The problem is that I don't know how to use it in the query now that it is showing as linked.

Comment: You cannot just insert in a linked server, you must specify the instance, schema and table/view. Check this examples https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-and-configure-a-linked-server-in-sql-server-management-studio/

Comment: Try With "insert into" ,for linked server select * into not works

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to quote the server name:

```sql
insert into [44.3.1.112,4230].Database.Schema.Table...
```

or, if `quoted_identifiers` is on (as it should be), you can use the more standards-compliant double quotes:

```sql
insert into "44.3.1.112,4230".Database.Schema.Table...
```

Comment: Tried Insert INTO [44.3.1.112,4230].CTixAnalysis.dbo.EventType
Select * from CTixAnalysis.dbo.EventType and I get a primary key violation but the table on the linked server is empty.

Comment: I am missing something here "Schema" maybe?  i have [44.3.1.112,4230].TheNameofMyDatabase.dbo.NameOfTable.  is dbo not Schema?

Comment: If you got a primary key violation, that means there are at least two records in your source table that share the same values for the primary key defined on the target table.
Since the source and target tables share the same name and reside in databases of the same name, that seems odd, but please check the PK definitions on both tables.

Comment: target table is empty.  It is trying to post back to the main table even though I have the linked server ip address in the quotes.  It is crazy

Comment: Target table is empty, but if the source table has two rows sharing the same values as the target table's PK, you'll get that error.